# How do I find, if a page has keywords from my list of keywords?

Tags: seo, keywords, search

I have list of keywords / phrases which based on SEO research I find as optimal.

**What is the best practice to check if a page already has the keywords / phrases from my list?**

The list has over 300 keywords / phrases. So I do not wanna do it one by one.
I prefer method, where I do not need to be admin of the page.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but it looks like your after a application or online service which would be considered off topic. However, I will point you in the right direction, search for [Keyword Density Checker](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Keyword+Density+Checker) in Google.

Comment: As well, SEO is not about keywords. Search engines do not match against keywords. That is not how it works. SEOs want your attention and business and parrot the some 'ole bad advice over and over again. Search engines are largely semantic engines and have been for quite a while. They match intent and not keywords. It is not a linear process but one that is far more complex based upon semantic linguistics and trust models. So please - stop doing the keyword chase and just create fantastic content.

Comment: I agree with you that search engines are semantic engines and absolutely agree that great and unique content do the best job. Anyway I see how QS in AdWords get better if KW in its list and KW on page match and I see better result also via GWT. I would appreciate if you can answer my question :)